# Check if dates consecutives in array with starting date today

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, comparison, momentjs

I am trying to check if in this following array, the dates are consecutives with starting date today (07/01/2020).

```
var arrayDate = [
  '06/30/2020', '06/29/2020', '06/28/2020', '06/26/2020'
]
```

It should return

```
var nbDatesConsecutives = 3
```

On the other hand, this following example should return 0 :

```
var arrayDate = [
  '06/29/2020', '06/28/2020', '06/26/2020', '06/25/2020'
]
```

I have tried many times to resolve it but I still blocked. Here is one of my attempts :

```
let arrayDiff = []
arrayDate.map((element, i) => {
    arrayDiff.push(today.diff(moment(element), 'days'));
});
let previousValue = null;
arrayDiff.map((element, i) => {
    let currentValue = arrayDiff[i];
    if (i > 0) {
      if (currentValue > previousValue) {
        strike++;
      }
    }
    previousValue = currentValue;
})
```

Thanks !

Comment: Your example is barely an attempt with all the undefined variables, please try to provide at least a compilable example of what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of mapping to the day diff is good. Let me build on that:

You could...

- Get "today" as the start of the current day
- Map the dates to their difference to today, in days
- Find the first array index where this difference is no longer equal to the index plus one (since you expect an array like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in the perfect case, so e.g. `array[2]`=`2 + 1`=`3`)
- This first mismatching index is already your result, except in the case where the whole array has the expected dates, so no index will mismatch - in that case you return the length of the array

Here you can see it working:

```js
function getConsecutive (dates) {
  // Note: I hardcoded the date so that the snippet always works.
  // For real use, you need to remove the hardcoded date.
  // const today = moment().startOf('day')
  const today = moment('2020-07-01').startOf('day')

  const diffs = dates.map(date => today.diff(moment(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'days'))
  const firstIncorrectIndex = diffs.findIndex((diff, i) => diff !== i + 1)
  return firstIncorrectIndex === -1 ? dates.length : firstIncorrectIndex
}

// Outputs 4:
console.log(getConsecutive(['06/30/2020', '06/29/2020', '06/28/2020', '06/27/2020']))

// Outputs 3:
console.log(getConsecutive(['06/30/2020', '06/29/2020', '06/28/2020', '06/26/2020']))

// Outputs 0:
console.log(getConsecutive(['06/29/2020', '06/28/2020', '06/26/2020', '06/25/2020']))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice ! Thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are doing is 1) `currentValue > previousValue` instead you should have checked the difference, which must be 1 and when not 1 break the loop. So, here comes the mistake 2) you are using map function rather use simple for loop so that you can break.

`

```
function getConsecutiveDateCount(arrayDate) {
    let arrayDiff = [];
    let today = moment();

    arrayDate.map((element, i) => {
      arrayDiff.push(today.diff(moment(element), 'days'));
    });

    let strike = 0;

    arrayDiff.unshift(0); /// insert 0 for today

    let previousValue = arrayDiff[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < arrayDiff.length; i++) {
      currentValue = arrayDiff[i];

      if (currentValue - previousValue === 1) {
        strike++;
      } else {
        break;
      }

      previousValue = currentValue;
    }

    return strike;
  }
```

`